# Example of Java EE MDB email receiver

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jboss, seam, jakarta-mail

Is there an example available of a Maven-based (or Ant) implementation for a Java EE MDB email receiver?

I mean something like described on https://community.jboss.org/wiki/InboundJavaMail

But, when trying to implement this myself I easily come into a dependency hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java EE 6 SDK includes a "mail connector" sample program.  The source code is [here](http://java.net/projects/glassfish-samples/sources/svn/show/trunk/ws/javaee6/connectors/apps/mailconnector).  It includes a Resource Adapter that uses JavaMail, and an MDB to receive messages.